# How do I detect if a screen has predefined bitmap area rendered in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, screen, desktop

First off, the title may be misleading, cos I don't know how to formulate my question properly since english isn't my native lang.

The point is: I have a bitmap, an icon, that has been extracted from a desktop's screenshot. And I want to check if current screen state (that's rendering all apps I run at the moment) has that icon (in the bitmap) visible?

And the question is, what is the approach in Cocoa?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My goal is to write a macro application that will do something when something happens on the screen or in open app (possibly hidden).

Comment: Is this the only way to achieve your goal? What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: This question discusses finding the difference between two images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901404/create-a-mask-from-difference-between-two-images-iphone It's for the iPhone, but it seems easily adaptable for OS X. So just take another screenshot of the same area and compare them.

Comment: It is not wise to ask the same question twice on Stack Overflow. Make some edits to add more information to give this question a bump.

Comment: Anne, my goal is to write more or less a macro app, that will do something when something happens on the screen or in open (possibly hidden) app.

Wekwa, thanks, I'll take a look.

Kev, yeah, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a view or even any object is visible using

```
 if (object.superview)
```

To check the alpha (alpha = 1 is visible alpha = 0 is hidden

```
if (object.alpha == 1)
```

Or you can check for hidden objects like this:

```
if (object.hidden)
```

And check if object have been unhidden:

```
if (!object.hidden)
```