# Quartz : Getting the diff images of two images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, image-processing, core-graphics

I've following two images the background may be totally different image, e.g. not just plain color.

[image: Image number one] [image]

So basically I want to get the diff image of these two images i.e.

[image]

> The diff image of two images is the image with the same size but the
>   pixels are set to be transparent that haven't been changed. The difference image is constructed from the diff pixels with the color from the second image

I'm looking for the solution based on Core Graphics techniques, please don't suggest to run all over the pixels in loop. I do care about the performance.

As I'm new to Quartz I would like to know is it possible to achieve this with masks ? 
Or please suggest another approach !

**Update on using difference blending mode**
Actually if I use the difference blending mode it doesn't solve my problem as it doesn't keep right colors of the pixels. If I apply difference blend mode to above 2 images I'll get following

[image]

Which seems to have inverted colors for the pixels and then if I invert them I get following

[image]

Which actually is not what I wanted, as the pixel colors are totally different

Comment: Accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901404/create-a-mask-from-difference-between-two-images-iphone looks like it could help.

Comment: @rokjarc thanks for the link, but difference blend mode does is not a solution in my case, just updated the example images to demonstrate it.

Comment: What happens if you just draw one image onto the other after setting `CGContextSetBlendMode(kCGBlendModeDifference);` Doesn't that give you what you are after?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Please see my update question on applying difference blend mode

Comment: Btw... isn't the pink part of your example image supposed to be blue like the inverted image in the end of your question?

Comment: If the inverted image at the end of your updated question is not what you wanted, how exactly do you define the difference? The example you give in the top of your post is strange since it has the black text from image2 as black but the blue shape from image1 is not blue. Either both should be their original color or not, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @David Rönnqvist for the tip I've got my problem solved +2 to him :)

I've posted the solution in my blog here http://levonp.blogspot.com/2012/05/quartz-getting-diff-images-of-two.html

Answer (score 6):

You can blend any drawing in Core Graphics using

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(kCGBlendModeDifference);
```

By drawing the first image and then setting the blend mode to difference and drawing the second image you will get the difference (as I suggested in my comment). This gives you an inverted image (as seen in your updates question). To invert the image you can then fill the same rect with white color using (since the blend mode is still set to "difference").

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, frame);
```

---

Sample code to do all this (inside drawRect:) is seen below.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Your two images
CGImageRef img1 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ygsvt.png"] CGImage];
CGImageRef img2 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ay5DB.png"] CGImage];

// Some arbitrary frame
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100);

// Invert the coordinates to not draw upside down
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, frame.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// Draw original image
CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, img1);

// Draw the second image using difference blend more over the first
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDifference);
CGContextDrawImage(context, frame, img2);

// Fill the same rect with white color to invert 
// (still difference blend mode)
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, frame);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code David but as I've already mentioned the diff blending is not the solution from me, I've updated the question with better definition of difference image. Actually the diff image of two images is the image with the same size but the pixels are set to be transparent that haven't been changed. The difference image is constructed from the diff pixels with the color from the second image

Comment: So basically you want to use mask the second image where there are differences?

Comment: Yes exactly ! Any Ideas how to construct the mask ?

Comment: You can clip the context to a mask using: `CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, mask)` where mask is a CGImageRef in "DeviceGray" colorspace without alpha. You can create an image mask using `CGImageMaskCreate( ... params ...)`

Comment: You'll find the best explanation of CGImageMaskCreate in [the QuartzDemo sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html). Just search for it in the project (there is only on occurrence).

Comment: OK I'm going to try to get the right mask for me ! Will let you know about the result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11598/discussion-between-deimus-and-david-ronnqvist)